# minimize the maximum continious subarray in array of 0/1

Tags: greedy

**Algo question** 
 Binary array of 0/1 given  
**In one operation i can flip any array[index] of array i.e. 0->1 or 1->0
so aim is to minimize the maximum lenth of continious 1's or 0's by using atmost k flips** 
eg if 11111 if array and k=1 ,best is to make array as 11011 
**And minimized value of maximum continous 1's or 0's is 2** 
for 111110111111 and k=3 ans is 2 
I tried **Brute Force** (by trying various position flips) but its not efficient  
I think **Greedy** ,but can not figure out exactly  
 can you please help me for algo,**O(n) or similar**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be devised by reading each bit in order and recording the size of each continuous group of 1 into a list A.

Once you are done filling A, you can follow the algorithm narrated by the pseudocode below:

```
result = N
for i = 1 to N
    flips_needed = 0
    for a in A:
        flips_needed += <number of flips needed to make sure largest group remaining in a is of size i>
    if k >= flips_needed:
        result = flips_needed
        break
return result
```

N is the number of bits in the entire initial sequence.

The algorithm above works by dividing the groups of 1 into sizes of at most i. Whenever doing that requires <= k, we have the result we are looking for, as i starts from 1 and goes up. (i.e. when we found flips_needed <= k, we know the groups of 1 are as minimal as they can get)